# AWS CLI Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://iam.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am a beginner at using the AWS CLI.

I have run `aws configure` and setup my IAM user credentials.

Default region name: `[Africa (Cape Town)]: af-south-1`

When I try to run any command to interact with AWS resources, I get the below response:

> Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://iam.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/"

How can I troubleshoot this, from the network perspective I can reach most domains and different other subdomains off the `amazonaws` domain.

Comment: Where are you running the AWSCLI?

Comment: From an EC2 instance with in my public subnet in my VPC

Answer (score 1):

The `iam.af-south-1.amazonaws.com` DNS name does not resolve to an IP address because AWS IAM is a **global service**. It only operates out of the `us-east-1` region, accessed via `iam.amazonaws.com`.

You can test this by doing a few tests:

- `curl https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` -- works
- `curl https://iam.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` -- does not work
- `curl https://iam.amazonaws.com` -- works

As to *WHY* your system is attempting to access `iam.af-south-1.amazonaws.com`, I'm not sure. It shouldn't be doing that, even if you set the default region to `af-south-1`.

Comment: I guess it kind of overrides the default, I changed default region to us-east-1 and all is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, but that really shouldn't be happening. Most strange!